# Performance of my MPI code does not improve when I use two NUMA nodes (dual Xeon chips)

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, performance-testing, openmpi, mpich

I have a computer, Precision-Tower-7810 dual Xeon E5-2680v3 @2.50GHz × 48 threads.
Here is result of $lscpu

```
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          48
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-47
Thread(s) per core:              2
Core(s) per socket:              12
Socket(s):                       2
NUMA node(s):                    2
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
CPU family:                      6
Model:                           63
Model name:                      Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v3 @ 2.50GHz
Stepping:                        2
CPU MHz:                         1200.000
CPU max MHz:                     3300,0000
CPU min MHz:                     1200,0000
BogoMIPS:                        4988.40
Virtualization:                  VT-x
L1d cache:                       768 KiB
L1i cache:                       768 KiB
L2 cache:                        6 MiB
L3 cache:                        60 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0-11,24-35
NUMA node1 CPU(s):               12-23,36-47
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     KVM: Mitigation: VMX disabled
```

My MPI code is based on basic MPI (Isend, Irecv, Wait, Bcast). Fundamentally, the data will be distributed and sent to all processors. On each processor, data is used to calculate something and its value is changed. After the above procedure, the amount of data on each processor is exchanged between all processors. This work is repeated to a limit.

Now, the main issue is that when I increase the number of processors within the limit of one chip (24 threads), performance increases. However, performance does not improve while the number of processors > 24 threads.
An example:

```
$mpiexec -n  6 ./mywork : 72s
$mpiexec -n 12 ./mywork : 46s
$mpiexec -n 24 ./mywork : 36s
$mpiexec -n 32 ./mywork : 36s
$mpiexec -n 48 ./mywork : 35s
```

I have tried on the both OpenMPI and MPICH, obtained result is the same. So, I think issue  of physical connect type (NUMA nodes) of two chips. It is assumption of mine, I have never used a really supercomputer. I hope anyone know this issue and help me. Thank you for reading.

Comment: Are you sure your processes are pinned to a core? Use `numctl` or `hwloc` to pin them.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion. I have never used `numctl` or `hwloc` before. After seeing your comment, I have installed `numactl-v2.0.14`. However, I do not know the way how it is added to the batch file. My file `run.sh: #!/bin/bash
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 nohup  mpirun -np 24 ./LBMtest > out.LBMtest.txt &`

Comment: T tried `#!/bin/bash
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1
export NM_BIND_THREADS_TO_CORES=1
nohup numactl -N 0 -C 0-47 mpirun -np 48 ./LBMtest > out.LBMtest.txt &` but issue is not resolved. Can you suggest to me some documents on this issue?

Comment: I think you have the basics of how to use numactl. Sorry, without knowing much more about your code I don't have any other ideas.